# A file inside a Pycharm project does not have any Local History after an external change

Tags: pycharm

Inside a project that has been active for a few weeks I have a `Makefile` in which I had been making periodic changes. I just noticed its Local History is not working. It's not only empty but no new entries are being created.

[image]

The problem seems to have happened after I did some editing in `Visual Studio Code` to that same `Makefile`. That's something I do regularly - and `PyCharm` is usually "good" with it: it will see those as `External Changes` and update in the Local History appropriately.

Any ideas how to get `Pycharm` back on track with this one file?  Note that other files in the project that I have looked at still have correct Local History.  I am on `Pycharm Professsional 2022.3.1`